# Raising an event from a mocked object using Rhino

Tags: c#, unit-testing, events, nunit, rhino-mocks

I have a problem with raising an event on a mocked object. I am using Rhino Mocks 3.4. I have studied similar questions, but failed to reproduce any of the suggested solutions.

I have a class -- Foo -- which have a private method, that is only accessed by event invokation by an injected interface -- IBar.

How do I raise the event IBar.BarEvent, from a RhinoMock object, so I can Test the method in Foo?

Here is my code:

```
[TestFixture]
public sealed class TestEventRaisingFromRhinoMocks
{

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        MockRepository mockRepository = new MockRepository();
        IBar bar = mockRepository.Stub<IBar>();

        mockRepository.ReplayAll();

        Foo foo = new Foo(bar);

        //What to do, if I want invoke bar.BarEvent with value =123??

        Assert.That(foo.BarValue, Is.EqualTo(123));

    }

}


public class Foo
{
    private readonly IBar _bar;
    private int _barValue; 

    public Foo(IBar bar)
    {
        _bar = bar;
        _bar.BarEvent += BarHandling; 
    }

    public int BarValue
    {
        get { return _barValue; }
    }

    private void BarHandling(object sender, BarEventArgs args)
    {
        //Eventhandling here: How do I get here with a Rhino Mock object? 
        _barValue = args.BarValue;
    }
}


public interface IBar
{
    event EventHandler<BarEventArgs> BarEvent;
}


public class BarEventArgs:EventArgs
{
    public BarEventArgs(int barValue)
    {
        BarValue = barValue;
    }
    public int BarValue { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `IEventRaiser`, which you can get via

```
bar.BarEvent += null;
var eventRaiser = LastCall.IgnoreArguments().GetEventRaiser();
```

Then, when you want to raise the event, you can call `eventRaiser.Raise` with the required arguments, e.g. sender and event args (depends on your event handler definition).

(Edit: this is based on Rhino.Mocks 3.1!)

Answer (score 5):

Something like this I think:

```
bar.Raise(x => x.BarEvent += null, this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx#Howtoraiseevents

Comment: FWIW, He's using Rhino.Mocks 3.4

Comment: Ah, I missed that bit in the question.